# How to catch ESC key press with WndProc?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to catch an ESC KeyPress using WndProc?

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean while your form has focus, in which case I'd go with tommeib's solution. If not, you should provide more info.

Comment: This is not relevant for the OP, but for others who end up here the usual best way to handle Esc in a WinForms program is by overriding ProcessCmdKey. See the answer by Hans Passant on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468200/key-events-processcmdkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing it this way? Why not set the `PreviewKey` property of the Form to `true` and set a global event handler for `KeyUp` and check it...

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Esc){
   //...
}
```

Comment: This won't work with certain keys, but it seems to work fine with the escape key. BTW, I believe it's KeyPreview.

Comment: Sank's, I already do that. I'm just searching for alternative way )

Answer (score 5):

Another option (for forms):

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
  int VK_ESCAPE = 27;
  if (m.Msg == Win32Constants.WM_KEYDOWN && (int)m.WParam == VK_ESCAPE)
  {
    // ...
  }
  return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}
```

Comment: `WM_KEYDOWN` is `0x0100`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the [`WM_CHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message and check `WParam`.

Answer (score 0):

(msg==WM_KEYDOWN) && (wParam==VK_ESCAPE) ... ops it was c#... sorry , that is win32 api way