Alt key skips KeyUp event
In the below code, holding 'x' causes the drawn cube to rotate. Pressing 'alt' causes the KeyUp event for 'x' to skip, and the cube continues rotating until 'x' is pressed again. This makes me think the alt key is causing the form to lose focus.
I tried using a preview key down event to catch alt key presses but this didn't fix it.  I'd prefer not to check IsKeyDown.
I don't necessarily want to disable things like Alt+F4. I'm deliberately not using the Alt key for any purpose in my app. But a user might hit the Alt key and have this issue.

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private float rotationAngle = 0;
        private bool rotationKeyDown = false;
    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
            timer1.Interval = 32;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    
        public struct Point3D
        {
            public float X, Y, Z;
    
            public Point3D(float x, float y, float z)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
                Z = z;
            }
        }
    
        public class Matrix4x4
        {
            private float[,] matrix = new float[4, 4];
    
            public static Matrix4x4 CreateRotationY(float angle)
            {
                Matrix4x4 result = new Matrix4x4();
                result.matrix[0, 0] = result.matrix[2, 2] = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
                result.matrix[0, 2] = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
                result.matrix[2, 0] = -(float)Math.Sin(angle);
                result.matrix[1, 1] = result.matrix[3, 3] = 1;
                return result;
            }
    
            public Point3D MultiplyPoint(Point3D p)
            {
                return new Point3D(
                    p.X * matrix[0, 0] + p.Y * matrix[0, 1] + p.Z * matrix[0, 2],
                    p.X * matrix[1, 0] + p.Y * matrix[1, 1] + p.Z * matrix[1, 2],
                    p.X * matrix[2, 0] + p.Y * matrix[2, 1] + p.Z * matrix[2, 2]
                );
            }
        }
    
    private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
    {
    e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
    }
    
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
            {
                rotationKeyDown = true;
            }
        }
    
        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
            {
                rotationKeyDown = false;
            }
        }
    
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rotationKeyDown == true)
            {
                rotationAngle += 10;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawCube(e.Graphics, this.ClientSize.Width / 2, this.ClientSize.Height / 2);
        }
    
        private void DrawCube(Graphics g, int cx, int cy)
        {
            int side = 100;
            Point3D[] vertices = {
            new Point3D(-1, -1, -1),
            new Point3D(1, -1, -1),
            new Point3D(1, 1, -1),
            new Point3D(-1, 1, -1),
            new Point3D(-1, -1, 1),
            new Point3D(1, -1, 1),
            new Point3D(1, 1, 1),
            new Point3D(-1, 1, 1)
            };
    
            Matrix4x4 rotationMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(rotationAngle * (float)Math.PI / 180);
            Point[] projectedPoints = new Point[vertices.Length];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                Point3D rotated = rotationMatrix.MultiplyPoint(vertices[i]);
                projectedPoints[i] = IsoProject(rotated, cx, cy, side);
            }
    
            int[] edges = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7 };
            for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i += 2)
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, projectedPoints[edges[i]], projectedPoints[edges[i + 1]]);
            }
        }
    
        private Point IsoProject(Point3D p, int cx, int cy, int scale)
        {
            float x = p.X - p.Y;
            float y = p.X + p.Y - 2 * p.Z;
            return new Point((int)(cx + x * scale / 2), (int)(cy + y * scale / 2));
        }
    }


Try setting: Form.KeyPreview = true;

I added this.KeyPreview = true; but I'm still having the issue.

Put a breakpoint in Form1_KeyUp. Does it hit? Also, do you have a menu? Alt key will activate a menu.

I didn't add a menu.  In KeyUp, I put: if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt){breakpoint} else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt){breakpoint} and if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X){breakpoint} but the breakpoints get skipped.

Well, Alt key is special and can break things like that. It's been years since I worked with that, so can't remember the details.

May be this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468200/key-events-processcmdkey
